# How to use Redux-Form with React-Bootstrap?

Tags: redux-form

I am trying to use "redux-form": "^6.7.0" with "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0"

My Component renders nicely, but when I press Submit, what I see is an empty object.

*note: I have tried wrapping the Config with connect first, and as show below, first wraping it with redux-form and then with the  from react-redux connect()*

**Configuration.js**

```
class Config extends Component {
    render() {
        const { ServerPort, UserID, PortNumber, WWWUrl, SourcePath, FMEPath, pickFile, pickFolder, handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <Form horizontal onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="serverPortBox">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>Watson Port:</Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={(<Tooltip id="tt1">TCP port for Watson to use</Tooltip>)}>
                            <Field name="WatsonPort" component={FormControl}
                                type="number" min="1024" max="65535" placeholder={ServerPort} />
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

 ......

const CForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'configuration' // a unique name for this form
})(Config);

const Configuration = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CForm)

export default Configuration
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form

......

const reducerList = {
    GLVersion,
    ServerConfig,
    ServerStats,
    form: formReducer
}

export default combineReducers(reducerList)
```

Main Package **Dashboard.js**

*what i see in the debugger is that config is an empty object*

```
    <Panel className='configPanel'
      collapsible header="Configuration"
      eventKey="1"
      defaultExpanded={true}>
      <Configuration onSubmit={(config) => writeConfig(config)} />
    </Panel>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2917

Oh, this was a great mystery. I followed the advice in https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2210 and both the warning about additional props and the empty submit stopped.

It seems you have to wrap the Bootstrap in your custom component (why?, I don't know). Also make sure you custom component is a stateless funcitonal component, or after the first key press, you field will blur and lose focus.

There are some warnings in the documentation of redux-form about this.

**my custom field component FieldInput**

```
  const FieldInput = ({ input, meta, type, placeholder, min, max }) => {
        return (
            <FormControl
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                min={min}
                max={max}
                value={input.value}
                onChange={input.onChange} />
        )
    }
```

and I invoke it like this:

```
<Field name="ServerPort"
   type='number' 
   component={FieldInput} 
   placeholder={ServerPort} 
   min="1024" max="65535" 
/>
```

see also: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1750

So now, the definition of FieldInput and Config look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Form, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Col, Button, Tooltip, OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap'
import * as Act from '../dash/actions.js'
import FaFolderOpen from 'react-icons/lib/fa/folder-open'
import FaFileCodeO from 'react-icons/lib/fa/file-code-o'

const FieldInput = ({ input, meta, type, placeholder, min, max }) => {
    return (
        <FormControl
            type={type}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            min={min}
            max={max}
            value={input.value}
            onChange={input.onChange} />
    )
}

const Config = ({ ServerPort, UserID, PortNumber, WWWUrl, SourcePath, FMEPath, pickFile, pickFolder, handleSubmit }) => {
    return (
        <Form horizontal onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormGroup controlId="serverPortBox">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>Watson Port:</Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                    <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={(<Tooltip id="tt1">TCP port for Watson to use</Tooltip>)}>
                        <Field name="ServerPort" type='number' min="1024" max="65535" component={FieldInput} placeholder={ServerPort}  />
                    </OverlayTrigger>
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>
```

Comment: hi this works well with other bootstrap fields. but how can we manage with Form control select field ? Because it is not selecting default option. FYI I used onChange and Value which I managed through state.

Comment: I've made one custom component work for both "input" and "select" by not forcing a `type`, instead passing through any ...extraProps to the `FormControl`.  That way for an input I can pass `type="text"`; for a dropdown `componentClass="select"` and some `<option ...>` children (which is just syntax sugar to a prop called `children`).  Both react-redux's `<Field>` and bootstrap's `<FormControl>` pass through any extra props, including children, so in the end the `<option>`s become children of the `<input>`!  Don't have answer to HeratPatel's question about default though.

Answer (score 8):

Some props required by `<FormControl>` are passed inside `props.input` from `<Field>`, see http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/Field.md/#props

To pass all those props in a generic way, instead of doing it explicitly, you can use the following function:

```
const ReduxFormControl = ({input, meta, ...props}) => {
     return <FormControl {...props} {...input} />
};
```

and then inside the form:

```
<Field component={ReduxFormControl} ... />
```

This way, value, onChange, etc. are all passed as expected to `<FormControl>`.